# how to lookup data from diffrent JavaPairRDD in Spark 2.1.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Hello I am very new to Spark and big data programming. I am developing a report generation application with spark, which loads huge amount of data from sequence files from s3 location and do some filtering and criteria matching. I need help on how we can get or lookup data from diffrent RDD.
I have 1 RDD where i have filtered data. and other rdd is a raw.

```
JavaPairRDD<String,List<DepartmentBudget>> result = criteriaRDD.mapToPair(new reportCriteriaMatching());
```

This is giving me correct report data in which String is a report name and list of DepartmentBudget is the data in which department id and department name is present.

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Iterable<Employee>> departmentEmpoyeeRDD = employeeRDD.groupBy(emp -> emp.getDepartment().getDepartmentname());
```

In above departmentEmpoyeeRDD we grouped all employee based on department name.

Now I want to create report from resultRDD where i need to get all employees from each department.

I tried with broadcast variable but departmentEmpoyeeRDD is too huge to broadcast. it is around 13GB in size. So, i am getting OOM exception with broadcasting this RDD.

Please suggest !

Thank you.